# Different results with same hyperparameter in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using caret to train a classification model with Random Forest. I have tried different hyperparameter values for mtry in different combinations. The surprising result for me is, that the same values for mtry lead to different results in different combinations.

Example: The following code

```
TControl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
rfGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = c(7, 8, 9))
set.seed(123)
rformodel1 <- train(Target ~., data=training, method="rf", tuneGrid=rfGrid, trControl=TControl)
rformodel1
```

produces

```
  mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
  7     0.7991246  0.5983991
  8     0.8027609  0.6055879
  9     0.8009764  0.6021028

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 8.
```

Now, I change the mtry parameter from the sequence 7 to 9 to only 8 as single value expecting that the result is the same as shown above for mtry=8:

```
TControl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
rfGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = 8)
set.seed(123)
rformodel2 <- train(Target ~., data=training, method="rf", tuneGrid=rfGrid, trControl=TControl)
rformodel2
```

But surprisingly I get the following result with a different Accuracy and Kappa:

```
  Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.7972727  0.5946954

Tuning parameter 'mtry' was held constant at a value of 8
```

I get the same differences when I change the sequence for example to 6 to 8.

Only in that case, when I repeat the same code I get the same result.

Does anyone have an explanation for the cause of these discrepancies and how I can fix them?

Comment: Your `set.seed` only applies at the start of the calculation, so in the first example the seed will have a different value once it gets to the `mtry=8` section.

Comment: In addition to @AndrewGustar's point that the random number sequences mean different seeds for different runs when you switch the order of `mtry` values, it seems worth asking whether these `mtry` values are making any difference at all. Both `Accuracy` and `Kappa` values look very similar between these. I'm curious if the models they produce give different predictions: if not, they might be the same, if so, do they work equally well with different thresholds (assuming here you have >50% of votes)?

Comment: For more details you may need to include data to make this reproducible.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers. I assumed that set.seed is internally reinitialized for every parameter (combination). Understand the behaviour of train now better. 
@Michael: The results of the models are really very similar.

Comment: Am usually using Python and sklearn where the GridSearchCV works the way, I assumed too for train.